# How to create customized side control bar in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geoext

I could create a simple map using OpenLayers. But I want to have a customised side control bar.

The one I created:
[image]

The one I want to create:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoExplorer is written using [Ext JS 3.4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs3) and [Geo Ext](http://www.geoext.org/) Js Libraries. Try this [tutorial from Open Geo](http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/). With this tutorial you will create similar app